# Как вывести {variables: "{"money1":3,"money2":3}"}

Tags: javascript, php, json

Из бд json возвращает, записанные в него переменные `money1` и `money2`, в таком виде:

```
{variables: "{"money1":3,"money2":3}"}
```

Как их вывести?

Comment: Кавычки какие-то кривые... кажется он в принципе неправильный...`variables: "{"` после этого должна пойти ошибка.

Comment: `{variables: {"money1":3,"money2":3} }` - ошибки нет. `{variables: "{"money1":3,"money2":3}"}` - ошибка есть. Для начала запишите валидную json строку в бд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное вам стоит открыть это [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Ну и собственно:

```
$result = json_decode($json,  true);

echo $result['variables']['что вам надо'];
```

Comment: Вы сами-то пробовали запускать этот код?

Comment: Вопрос был как вывести json? или почему мой json не валидный?